# Globally-accessible data storage in a menu driven program?

Tags: delphi, menu, global

I'm new to Stack Overflow but I find myself seeking some of the best programming solutions on this site.  So I have a question to ask.

I am writing a program in Delphi that is a TUI menu-driven program for a local business client. They have asked me to keep the user interface the same as in the old program (written in BASIC for MS-DOS, dated in 1982) so it is all menu driven with global data being stored in files and reloaded by the program. Each sub-menu is a program in and of itself run by the active menu (also a program).

I have written my own TUI framework and UI manager for displaying menus and sub-menus.  The UI manager contains an overridden method called "Draw" to display the menu and another overridden method called "OnEvent" which handles keyboard events in the UI.  **My first question is would you consider this to be an appropriate method for making a menu-driven program containing sub-menus?** An example of how this works is such:

```
type
  TMenu1 = class(TExtendedUIManager)
  private
    procedure OnEvent (c: Char); override;
  end;

type
  TSubMenu1 = class(TExtendedUIManager)
  end;

procedure TMenu1.OnEvent (c: Char);
var
  Next: TExtendedUIManager;
begin
  if c = '2' then begin
    Next := TSubMenu1.Create;
    Self.Start(Next);
    Next.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**My other question is what would be an appropriate way of sharing data between menus?** For example, if I wanted my TSubMenu1 class to return a string when a method is called, how would I make it accessible to other sub-menus that do not interact with it? (Sorry if the question is vague). I have the Singleton pattern in mind but I've also thought of having the UI manager store a reference to some object for data storage and each time a new sub-menu is run, pass in the reference to the new sub-menu (UI manager). The conundrum is finding out which one works best. Or even if my menu-driven framework is decent.

Opinions are welcomed and any advice is appreciated.  Thanks for your time and help!

--Todd

Comment: Can you explain why you need to write your own framework and UI Manager rather than just using standard Delphi components? And what is 'TUI'? Do you mean GUI??

Comment: TUI == Text User Interface. If it were me, I'd really want to use something like ncurses to make the TUI implementation tolerable, but I assume Delphi implies the Windows environment -- for which ncurses is probably less well suited.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have to use Windows but my TUI framework serves a similar purpose to ncurses. I wrote my own because the original program has certain UI characteristics like all text-prompts containing periods for whitespace, multiple prompts per UI, etc. Writeln and Readln were not sufficient.

Comment: "my other question is..." should usually imply opening a second question on SO

Comment: If you're re-writing the application, give them an upgrade: You can keep the same menu organization but make the application a true GUI application. I'm absolutely certain there's no good reason to keep the text based interface. Example: Put 3 large buttons on a form, you got yourself an 3 option menu. The user can click the buttons (so it behaves like all Windows applications), the user can tab around and press enter, and you can register accelerator keys so they can use one key press access if that's what they want.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I had thought about it but wasn't sure if it'd be as decent (the client said they don't want any major changes - they're used to pressing keys to navigate menus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"My other question is what would be an appropriate way of sharing data between menus?"***

You can share the data by using class methods and properties. By using these, you can even access them even without create instance of the class. For more info go through [this Link](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/classmethods.htm).

Below is sample code which will share `List`.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ---
    ---
  private
    { Private declarations }
    class var List: TStringList;
    ---
  end;
var
  Form1, Form2: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.List.Add('4');
  Form2.List.Add('5');

  ShowMessage(TForm1.List.Text);
end;

initialization
  StrList := TStringList.Create;
  TForm1.List := TStringList.Create;
  TForm1.List.Add('1');
  TForm1.List.Add('2');
  TForm1.List.Add('3');
  ShowMessage(TForm1.List.Text);


finalization
  FreeAndNil(TForm1.List);
end.
```

Comment: This sounds like what I'm after for my programming design. My version of Delphi (7.0) doesn't support static instance fields but I've decided to init the list in the root then pass the list by reference to child nodes in the menu tree.

Comment: I finally decided to go with something like this. I ended up creating a Context object for storing references to the active data (e.g. configuration info, the SQLite database reference, and menu settings) and just passing the context each time I call a new menu or screen. I'm not sure how well it's accepted among programming communities but I tried to build something similar to how the Android API functions ("Activities" calling objects through a given Context) since I recently started playing with that. Anyway, thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'll freely admit this is thinking aloud territory for me, but the first thing that caught my eye was this:

> ```
> procedure TMenu1.OnEvent (c: Char);
> var
>   Next: TExtendedUIManager;
> begin
>   if c = '2' then begin
>     Next := TSubMenu1.Create;
>     Self.Start(Next);
>     Next.Free;
>   end;
> end;
> ```

It feels like the end condition of this sort of programming is going to be huge decision trees of `if c = '2' then ... else if c = '3' then ... else` and so on. This does get tedious to write and maintain; if feasible, an array mapping input character with a function to execute is often far easier to maintain.

```
[['2', foo_create],
['3', foo_delete],
['4', foo_ship],
['d', foo_destroy_all],
['`', foo_return_to_previous_menu]]
```

When a new character comes in, you would look up the corresponding function in the table and execute it. Once you're done, return to waiting.

You could further extend this array to keep track of arguments that are required and values returned from each function. When you execute a function, store its return value in a global variable somewhere, and keep track of what types were returned. (Perhaps Delphi's type system is sophisticated enough that it is trivial, and not even worth mentioning.) When you execute a new function, check to see if the type of the 'current' returned result is suitable to pass to the desired function. (You could even grey-out the menu entries if the types are wrong, to indicate to the user that this combination won't work.)

```
/* key function    arg   ret types */
[['2', foo_create, NULL, FOO],
['3', foo_delete, FOO, NULL],
['4', foo_ship, FOO, NULL],
['d', foo_destroy_all, NULL, NULL],
['`', foo_return_to_previous_menu, NULL, NULL]]
```

I hope this is useful in some fashion. :)

Comment: I understand where you're coming from with this.  There are parts of the program where the menu expects numeric input or single character input depending on which menu is used.  Delphi (my version at least) doesn't have any form of mapping aside from creating records and storing them in an array.

The question I'm pondering is whether my design of using a tree for storing sub-menus being run (main menu is the root node) or if I should keep them all at the same level by using some implementation of a list.